# Is it possible to enable Excel Manual Calculation for specific formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula that makes an API request every time it's executed, which makes it slow. I'd like to prevent Excel from automatically recalculating cells containing this formula but still automatically recalculate other cells.

I've tried setting calculation mode to Manual with:

`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

However this prevents other cells without my formula from calculating automatically.

Another idea I've had is to check if a cell has been "frozen" and then return it's current value instead of calling the API for a new value. The issue with this is that Excel doesn't provide a way to exit the function without altering the cell value.

```
Function MyFormula() As Variant

   If CellIsFrozen() Then
       MyFormula = Application.Caller.Value  'return current value
   Else
       MyFormula = GetNewValueFromAPI()  'expensive call to server
   End If

End Function
```

My issue with the above is that `Application.Caller.Value` returns the cell value by performing a recalculation and results in an infinite recursion.

FYI - the `CellIsFrozen` method is just an example sub that would somehow check whether the cell was called automatically or manually.

I'm also aware of `Application.Caller.Value2` and `.text`, unfortunately these don't help me. `Value2` also causes a recalculation, and `text` just returns a string representation (which is not useful because it could be "######" if the value is a date and the column is too narrow).

Is there a way to interrupt Excel's recalculation process for specific formulas?

Otherwise, is it possible to extract a value of a cell without performing a recalculation - I'm guessing that Excel stores the value somewhere because it's visible on the worksheet, it makes no sense to insist on recalculating every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an UDF in the cell, I will like to make it like this workaround. 
For demo and test, Only used a single cell A1 in "Sheet1" , instead of using any API, I used `WorksheetFunction.RandomBetween` May use range and array if multiple cells are used.

In "Sheet1" cell A1 used `=myFormula()`

in a module

```
Public Flag As Boolean, LastVal As Variant

Public Function MyFormula() As Variant
   If Flag Then
   MyFormula = GetNewValueFromAPI()  'expensive call to server
   Else
   MyFormula = LastVal
   End If
End Function

Function GetNewValueFromAPI() As Variant
GetNewValueFromAPI = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 1000)
End Function
```

Sub `CalcA1` in `Module1` would be used to recalculate A1 whenever necessary. It could be called from any events also according to actual requirement.

```
Sub CalcA1()
Flag = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Dirty
Flag = False
End Sub
```

In workbook Open event the the `LastVal` was calculated with Flag as true and then Flag was reset to false to prevent further calling `GetNewValueFromAPI`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Flag = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Dirty
LastVal = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Flag = False
End Sub
```

In Worksheet_Calculate event of  Sheet1 the `LastVal` is being recorded.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
LastVal = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Working Demo[image]

Regret, I came across this post (A Real Good Question) late, since We had  already been used something in this line in our workplace. Thanks to @Pawel Czyz for editing the post it came under Active List today only.

Comment: This is a great answer and is a solution to my issue. My only remaining problem is that if my `MyFormula` function takes arguments, then the `LastVal` would vary depending on which cell and arg combination calls it. So `LastVal` would probably have to be a collection of values (perhaps indexed by cell location?), if I used the formula across 1000s of cells then that's quite a lot to keep in memory.

Comment: I don't think `myformula` taking arguments will make any difference. since practically `myformula` is only encompassing   `GetNewValueFromAPI()` and any argument will be finally passed to later and whatever the argument may be the final result would be stored in `LastVal` or `LastValArr`(in mt 2nd answer involving multiple cells)  till that would be recalculated on users choice.

Comment: Regarding holding 1000  values in a array in memory,  AFAIK  that it won’t be  a problem, may be of  improve performance in comparison of storing them in a blank sheet. (In fact before answering your comment, I tried the this option  but refrained to share it as I think it will only degrade and complicate the performance) . May some experts with in depth knowledge may throw some light in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

In the context my previous answer to the post involving single cell, i also want share our old experience involving multiple cells. that days We used the formula in an indexed fashion like `=myformula(1)...` etc and stored it in a global array. Now today **thanks to your great idea of `Caller` function**. I recreated another improvised solution involving multiple cells.

[image]

Here again in module1

```
Global Flag As Boolean, LastValArr(1 To 10, 1 To 2) As Variant, Ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range

Public Function MyFormula() As Variant
Dim Adr As String, X As Integer
   If Flag Then
   MyFormula = GetNewValueFromAPI()  'expensive call to server
   Else
   Adr = Application.Caller.Address
    For X = 1 To 10
        If InStr(1, LastValArr(X, 2), Adr) > 0 Then
        MyFormula = LastValArr(X, 1)
        Exit For
        End If
    Next
   End If
End Function

Function GetNewValueFromAPI() As Variant
GetNewValueFromAPI = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 1000)
End Function

Sub CalcA1()
Flag = True
Rng.Dirty
Flag = False
Ws.Range("F1").Value = IIf(Flag, "On", "Off")
End Sub

Sub ToggleFlag()
Flag = Not Flag
Ws.Range("F1").Value = IIf(Flag, "On", "Off")
If Flag Then Rng.Dirty
End Sub
```

in Workbook_Open event

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim X As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = Ws.Range("A1:A5")
Set Rng = Union(Rng, Ws.Range("C1:C5"))
Flag = True
Rng.Dirty
Flag = False
Ws.Range("F1").Value = IIf(Flag, "On", "Off")
End Sub
```

in Sheet1 Worksheet_Calculate event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim X As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
X = 1
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
    LastValArr(X, 1) = Cell.Value
    LastValArr(X, 2) = Cell.Address
    X = X + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

**Edit:** On second thought after initial feel good of posting the Demo answer, I found it lacks User friendliness and ease of copy pasting UDF formulas while working in Excel  Therefore i tried improvise it further so it could be used by users don't have access to VBA code and could work with copy paste of the UDF.

So 1st I came across a solution to store the Last Values in a temp sheet (may be Very Hidden Sheet). with apprehension that working with cell access may degrade performance of the code, I refrained from posting it and I finally restored to Dictionary Object.

This solution have added with basic advantage of Auto mapping of formula cells (by searching  `"=myformula"` in used range of the Sheet) to enable/disable calculation. This would enable users without access to code modules to work freely with UDF.

Here  reference to Microsoft scripting runtime has been added.

Code in module:

```
Global Flag As Boolean, Ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, Dict As Dictionary
Public Function MyFormula() As Variant
Dim Adr As String
   If Flag Then
   MyFormula = GetNewValueFromAPI() 'expensive call to server
   Else
   Adr = Application.Caller.Address
   'Debug.Print Adr
   MyFormula = IIf(Dict.Exists(Adr), Dict(Adr), 0)
   End If
End Function
Function GetNewValueFromAPI() As Variant
'Delay (2)
GetNewValueFromAPI = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 1000)
End Function
Sub CalcA1()
Flag = True
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.Dirty
'Debug.Print "in calA1"
Flag = False
Ws.Range("F1").Value = IIf(Flag, "On", "Off")
End Sub
Sub ToggleFlag()
Flag = Not Flag
Ws.Range("F1").Value = IIf(Flag, "On", "Off")
If Flag And Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.Dirty
End Sub
Sub BuildRange()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim Cell As Range
CalcCnt = CalcCnt + 1
    Set Rng = Nothing
    Dict.RemoveAll
    For Each Cell In Ws.UsedRange.Cells
        If Left(Cell.Formula, 10) = "=myformula" Then
        'Debug.Print "From Sht Calc -" & Cell.Address
            If Dict.Exists(Cell.Address) = False Then
            Dict.Add Cell.Address, Cell.Value
            Else
            Dict(Cell.Address) = Cell.Value
            End If

            If Rng Is Nothing Then
            Set Rng = Cell
            Else
            Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In Workbook_Open

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Dim X As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Dict = New Dictionary
Flag = True
BuildRange
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.Dirty
Flag = False
Ws.Range("F1").Value = IIf(Flag, "On", "Off")
End Sub
```

In Sheet Calculate event

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
BuildRange
End Sub

Comment: Edited answer with further improvised solution. May try and feedback.